# Power BI - show sum of a measure in all row in table visualization

Tags: powerbi

I have **dimCust** table as follow:

| CustID | CustName | CustAge | CustLoc |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 24 | X |
| 2 | B | 22 | Y |
| 3 | C | 32 | X |
| 4 | D | 16 | X |
| 5 | E | 54 | Z |
| 6 | F | 32 | Z |
| 7 | G | 27 | Y |
| 8 | H | 43 | X |
| 9 | I | 33 | Y |
| 10 | J | 25 | Z |
| 11 | K | 42 | Y |
| 12 | L | 51 | X |

And **Sales** table as follow:

| SalesID | CustID | Date | ProductID | Qty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 | 01 April 2023 | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 | 02 February 2023 | 3 | 2 |
| 3 | 4 | 13 February 2023 | 2 | 4 |
| 4 | 5 | 14 January 2023 | 4 | 3 |
| 5 | 2 | 13 April 2023 | 6 | 12 |
| 6 | 2 | 18 March 2023 | 3 | 3 |
| 7 | 6 | 21 February 2023 | 2 | 5 |
| 8 | 5 | 19 January 2023 | 3 | 6 |
| 9 | 3 | 17 April 2023 | 4 | 3 |
| 10 | 2 | 09 March 2023 | 5 | 10 |
| 11 | 6 | 22 March 2023 | 6 | 4 |
| 12 | 7 | 17 February 2023 | 4 | 10 |
| 13 | 6 | 19 February 2023 | 3 | 9 |
| 14 | 6 | 28 March 2023 | 2 | 7 |
| 15 | 4 | 21 January 2023 | 1 | 2 |

The relationship is as follow:

[image]

For now let's neglect the dimProduct table.

I then created a measure table consists of several measures as follow:

1. VisitQty = COUNT('Sales'[SalesID])
2. EarliestVisit = MINX(Sales, [Date])
3. LatestVisit = MAXX(Sales, [Date])
4. PeriodDay = DATEDIFF([EarliestVisit], [LatestVisit], DAY)
5. TotalPeriod = CALCULATE([PeriodDay], ALLSELECTED('dimCust'[CustID]))
6. TotalVisit = CALCULATE(COUNT('Sales'[SalesID]), ALLSELECTED('dimCust'[CustID]))
7. Visit/Period = DIVIDE([TotalVisit], [TotalPeriod])

Then in the report view, I chose Table Visualization and filled it with columns and measures:

- CustID taken from **dimCust** table
- Other columns are from the above measures

When I excluded CustName column, the last 3 columns consist of fix total value for each column in all rows as I wanted it.

[image]

And as I filtered the CustLoc using slicer, the total values will also be adjusted and each row will still be filled with the fix total value as follows:

[image]

But when I included the CustName column, it filters the CustID (only showing CustID that made purchase) and the values in last 3 columns changed become only for the particular rows.

[image]

How can I include the CustName column in the visualization, without filtering CustID and keep the last 3 columns filled with total values for each columns in all rows as before?

One more thing, I added other measure and included it in the table:

8. VV = DIVIDE(([VisitQty] - [Visit/Period]*[PeriodDay])^2, [PeriodDay])

The result for each row is correct, but why does the total value become zero?

[image]

Comment: There are 3 questions: 
1. Cust ID was filtered, 
2. Column TotalPeriod, TotalVisit and Visit/Period changed become total for each row only 
3. Total value of column VV become zero. 
Question 1 and 2 after adding CustName column. 

I already got the answer for question 1 to unfilter the CustID column by ticking "Show items with no data" in CustName field.